# jQuery adding class to html quote and escaping

Tags: jquery, css

I want to add a span with a class to every instance of double quotes within my blockquote.

I can check the contents of my blockquote and do a replace with anything other than the double quote. I'm assuming it's a problem with escaping the double quote, I've tried using slashes but I can't seem to get this to work.

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
$('blockquote:contains(")').each(function(){
$(this).html(
$(this).html().replace('&quot;','<span class=\'green\'>&quot;</span>')
);
});
});

<blockquote>
"Hello World"  
</blockquote>
```

Each quote should have a span around it and should display in a bold green style. In my example no span/class/style is added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should search and replace using `"` instead of `&quot;`, also, use a regular expression to match all `"`s in the `blockquote`:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('blockquote:contains(")').each(function() {
    $(this).html(
      $(this).html().replace(/"/g, '<span class="green">&quot;</span>')
    );
  });
});
```

```css
.green {
  color:green;
  font-size:14px;
  font-weight:bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<blockquote>
  &quot;Hello World"
</blockquote>
```